# replace part of text (hashtags) in instagram post

Tags: javascript

I use the instagram API to load the last 20 posts on a webpage. I retrieve the image, and the text of the post, which works well. Something else I try to achieve is to remove/replace all words starting with `#`, the so-called 'hashtags'. This is something I have trouble with. Currently, all of the 20 text are replaced with text 1, in which the hastags are successfully replaced.

My **JS** (relevant part of the code is at the end where you can see what I tried):

```
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=737514925.b2b5dcf.40705a1de9b54c039e840c52fe08b39c&count=20', true);

    request.onload = function() {
        if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
            // Success!
            var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
            for (var i=0;i < data.data.length;i++) {
                var container = document.getElementById('insta-feed');
                var imgURL = data.data[i].images.standard_resolution.url;
                var link = data.data[i].link;
                var text = data.data[i].caption.text;

                var imageDiv = document.createElement('div');
                imageDiv.setAttribute('class','insta-pic col-md-4');
                container.appendChild(imageDiv);

                var a = document.createElement('a');
                a.setAttribute('href', link);
                a.setAttribute('target', '_blank');

                var img = document.createElement('img');
                img.setAttribute('src',imgURL)
                img.setAttribute('class','img-instagram')

                var textDiv = document.createElement('div');
                textDiv.setAttribute('class','insta-text col-md-7');
                container.appendChild(textDiv);

                var p = document.createElement('p');
                p.innerHTML = text;

                imageDiv.appendChild(a);
                textDiv.appendChild(p);
                a.appendChild(img);

            }
        }


        // This is the (relevant) part that does not work
        var regexHash = /#\w+/gm;
        function replacer(){
            return '#hereWasSomeTag';
        }
        for (var i=0;i < data.data.length;i++) {
            var instaPostText = $('.insta-text p').html();
            $('.insta-text p').html(instaPostText.replace(regexHash, replacer));
        }
        // end of part that does not work

    };

    request.onerror = function() {
        // There was a connection error of some sort
    };
    request.send();
```

Or a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dirkjf/wytjkosx/42/) (mind you, on JSFiddle a different problem occurs with the exact same code, no text is replaced but all original texts are visible).

I imagine this issue is rather easily fixed, but with my poor understanding of JS I cannot figure out how.

Comment: Why not replace the text in your first `for` loop, before you set `innerHTML`? Because right now, your selector selects all of the `p` elements inside all of the `.insta-text` elements, then, since `html()` acts only on the first element of the collection, you only get the first text replaced.

Comment: `instaPostText.replace(regexHash, replacer)` what is the value of `replacer` here?

Comment: Your fiddle shows errors in the console, because you did not embed jQuery - fixed (in that regard) version: https://jsfiddle.net/vcmxpe39/1/

Comment: @04FS, totally missed that! Also for some reason I was stuck on creating a second loop. Great explanation on what I did wrong and how to fix it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    for (var i=0;i < data.data.length;i++) {
        var instaPostText = $('.insta-text p').html();
        $('.insta-text p').html(instaPostText.replace(regexHash, replacer));
    }
```

`$('.insta-text p')` here is selecting the same elements all the time, you did not limit this to any specific parent. And as is usually the case with jQuery getter methods, `.html()` will get you the HTML of the *first* matched element. The setters behave differently, so on the next line you set that replaced content of the *first* matched paragraph, for *all* matched paragraphs. That you do this multiple times in a loop, doesn’t change the outcome.

Why do this *after* the loop where you create those elements to begin with? Do it directly in the place where you *create* the text node:

```
        var p = document.createElement('p');
        p.innerHTML = text.replace(regexHash, replacer);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vcmxpe39/2/